# $f$ defined $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |x - y|^{1+ \alpha}$ Prove that $f$ is a constant.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be defined for all real $x$ and suppose that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |x - y|^{1+ \alpha}$ for all real $x$ and $y$, where $ \alpha > 0$.  Prove that $f$ is constant.

Proof:  I shall show that the derivative of $f$ is zero.  We have that $0 \leq | {f(y) - f(x)} | \leq |x-y|^{1+ \alpha}$. Dividing through by $|x-y|$ we have $0 \leq |\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x}| \leq |y - x|^{\alpha}$ and letting $y \rightarrow x$, we have shown that $f'(x) = \lim_{x \to y}|\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y - x}| = 0$.  Therefore $f$ is a constant.

Comment: You've wedged the limit between 0 and 0, so you can conclude it's zero. The derivative doesn't require the absolute value. You have $0 \leq f'(x) \leq 0$.

Comment: If the absolute value of something has limit $0$, then the something has limit $0$.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't sure if that was true or not!

Comment: The way to see this is that $x \mapsto |x|$ is a continuous function, so you can take the limit inside. Then you have $|x| = 0$ iff $x=0$.

Comment: Suppose  it is the year 1517 so  you have no calculus. Let $y-x=L $. And for $n\in \mathbb N$ let $x_{j,n}=x+jL/n$ for $0\leq j\leq n.$..... Then $|f(x)-f(y)|=$ $|\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} f(x_{j,n})-f(x_{j+1,n})|\leq$ $ \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}|f(x_{j,n})-f(x_{j+1,n})|\leq $ $n |L/n|^{1+\alpha}=$ $L^{1+\alpha}/n^{\alpha}$ which is arbitrarily close to $0$ if $n$ is large enough.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof looks fine, but note that $\lim\limits_{x \to y} \left| \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \right|$ is equal to $|f'(y)|$, not $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that at the end of the proof you write

> $f'(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to y} \bigg| \dfrac{f(y) - f(x) }{y - x}\bigg|$ ,

which is not exactly true. 
The derivative of $f(x)$ can be expressed as

$$
f'(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to y}  \dfrac{f(y) - f(x) }{y - x},
$$

thus we have

\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{x\to y} \bigg| \dfrac{f(y) - f(x) }{y - x} \bigg| = \big |\;f'(x)\big| = 0
\end{equation}
for any real $x$, which implies that $f'(x) = 0$ everywhere, so that $f$ is a constant.