# $ f(b)\leq f(a)+\omega(|b-a|)^\alpha$ with $\omega(0)=0$ and $\omega$ being differentiable implies that $f$ is smooth

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f,\omega:{\bf R}\to{\bf R}$ are functions with $\omega(0)=0$. Suppose for some $\alpha>1$, we have
>   $$
> f(b)\leq f(a)+\omega(|b-a|)^\alpha\quad\hbox{for all } a,b\in{\bf R}\tag{*}
> $$
>   If $\omega$ is differentiable at $x=0$, show that $f\in C^\infty({\bf R})$.

---

The original problem is given as follows:

> [image]

I think $\omega(|b-a|)^\alpha$ should be understood as $[\omega(|b-a|)]^\alpha$.

---

The condition (*) can be written as
$$
\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{h}\leq \frac{\omega(|h|)^\alpha-\omega(0)^\alpha}{h}.
$$
This seems to imply the differentiability of $f$. But how would one expect that $f$ could be smooth?

Comment: It seems that if one can show (similarly as in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1223377/9464) that $f'=0$, then we are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enlightened by this question:

[$f$ defined $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |x - y|^{1+ \alpha}$ Prove that $f$ is a constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1223377/9464)

I have an answer.

Since $\alpha>1$, the map $x\mapsto x^\alpha$ is differentiable at $x=0$. The inequality
$$
\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{h}\leq \frac{\omega(|h|)^\alpha-\omega(0)^\alpha}{h}.
$$
implies that for any $x\in{\bf R}$, 
$$
|f'(x)|\leq \omega(0)^{\alpha-1}\cdot\omega'(0)=0
$$
which implies that $f$ is a constant.